# Problems with aggregate function R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, sum, aggregate

I'm trying to consolidate some data and unfortunately it seems like I'm having some loss...

```
dataframe <-   Project    Subproject       Value      Date  
                 A           1              9       2017-03-08
                 A           2              5       2017-03-08
                 B           1              1       2017-03-08

overall <- aggregate(dataframe$Valeu, by=list(Date=dataframe$Date, Project=dataframe$Project), FUN=sum)
```

will return to me only this:

```
dataframe <-   Project      Value      Date  
                 A           14       2017-03-08
```

when what I want is this

```
dataframe <-   Project    Value      Date  
                 A          14       2017-03-08
                 B           1       2017-03-08
```

UPDATE: I tried again with the proposed solution and although R is telling me that there is a project B in my dataframe with said values and dates, my ggplot is telling me otherwise...

```
 ggplot(data = dataframe, aes(x = Date, y = Value, fill = Project)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + geom_text(data = dataframe, aes(label = Value, fill = Project), size=4)
```

It is only plotting the data from project A no matter what I do. However if I dont summarise/aggregate the data, it will plot both Projects for me as normal, however the geom_text will still continue to give the bar for Project A both numbers separately. My overall goal is to have a dataframe that is aggregated as I described so that I can plot my aggregated data cleanly with geom_text labeling my bars properly...

Comment: It works well for me using aggregate() apart from the error in dataframe$Valeu (should be dataframe$Value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Project, Date)%>%
  summarise(Value = sum(Value))
```

which gives:

```
  Project       Date Value

1       A 2017-03-08    14
2       B 2017-03-08     1
```

and can be plotted like `ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Date, y = Value, fill = Project)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

[image]

edit 1: based on OP's comment, to save the output in the dataframe, use something like `df %<>% ...` instead of `df %>% ...` from the library `magrittr`

Comment: your solution is supposedly saying that the data for project B is indeed in the dataframe but will not show up on my ggplot...

 ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Date, y = Value, fill = Project)) +
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity')

Comment: works for me. most likely you're just not saving the data properly. check the edit. Also, it's always helpful to add a new question for follow-ups not mentioned in the original question.

Comment: thank you @Aramis, i added a new, more elaborate question on my issue here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461936/ggplot-of-aggregated-data-frame-is-missing-values